# StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() hangs in one machine but never in another

Tags: c#, process, deadlock, redirectstandardoutput

Below codes have been **always** working in one environment.

Now we switched to a new environment (new VM), this codes do not work any more, it just hangs there until I manually close the pop-up window from cmd.exe. Obviously, there is some dead lock. But why it only happens in the new environment?? Even now it still works in the old environment.

```
        public static void Main()
    {
        Process p = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "c:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "/C START \"exeName\" /D %SystemDrive%\\somefolder start.bat",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                WorkingDirectory = "c:\\windows\\System32",
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        p.Start();

        string cv_error = null;
        Thread et = new Thread(() => { cv_error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); });
        et.Start();

        string cv_out = null;
        Thread ot = new Thread(() => { cv_out = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); });
        ot.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine("process finish " + p.HasExited); // This line prints "process finish true" successfully
        ot.Join(); // Stuck here until I manually close the popup window. But it works in another machine with this popup window stay open
        et.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("success" + p.ExitCode);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The start.bat looks like

```
@echo off
Echo "something"
mklink /D Logs "D:/logs"

Echo "Starting"
cd %~dp0\someFolder
.\ExeToInstallTools.exe arg1 // it will popup a console window showing the progress and logs

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error_handler
Exit /B 0

:error_handler
Echo "Failed"
Exit /B 1
```

---

UPDATE:

I have try to use some stackTrace tool to find the difference: when my app (process=4736) start the cmd process, cmd.exe /C turns into cmd.exe /K, it does not happen in the old machine.

[StackTraceToolView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5wvk.png)

Comment: My guess is that the `.Join()` waits for the threads to finish indefinitely. Try and add a value to them like `var finishedOt = ot.Join(10000);` and check the booleans. If `true` the thread did finish otherwise it is still running. Not a solution but a way to determine which thread causes the problem.

Comment: It does, but the two threads should exit as soon as `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` close, which should happen when the process exits. So it's most likely that the process isn't exiting, I think. @YuLan, can you investigate whether execution ever reaches the `p.WaitForExit()` line, and if so, does it complete that line and move onto the next one? Knowing whether it gets stuck would be really useful

Comment: It's also not clear why you're using cmd here. Can't you just execute `exeName` directly?

Comment: @canton7 thanks for the advice. I have checked that the codes reach p.waitForExit() and p.HasExited = true. I have printed the exitcode right after p.waitForExit() and it succeeded. The first join ot.Join() blocks everything and it never gets finish but always running.

Comment: @canton7 There are some other commands in the start.bat as well. it does not just run the exe

Comment: Try calling `p.Close()` or `p.Dispose()` after the `p.WaitForExit()` call. From [the source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Diagnostics.Process/System/Diagnostics/Process.cs,73f4515f17894282,references), it looks like stdout and stderr are only closed when the `Process` is closed

Comment: Tried that, but still the same..